# Python run separate scripts from my script

Tags: python, automation

I have 2 scripts, and I need to run one script from another, get its output, and assign it into variable inside the first script, and use it.

The second script need to give me some output of a text within 5-7 characters.

I tried to run this in my first script, but it didn't work.

```
import subprocess

capnum = subprocess.run(["../python3 test-ver2.py"])
print("Result: " % capnum.returncode)
```

Comment: You're just trying to get the output text of `../python3 test-ver2.py`?

Comment: Is the file in the same project folder? You should be able to import it. If the text generation is not already in a function I would do that. (check here)[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-call-function-from-another-file/]

Comment: @user17242583 the output of a script, inside test-ver2.py is a script that is running and the output of it is a 5-7 characters, now i need to use those characters inside my 1st script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `subprocess.getoutput()` is what you're looking for:

```py
import subprocess

capnum = subprocess.getoutput("..\\python3 test-ver2.py")
print(f"Result: {capnum}")
```

Comment: I'm getting this error:
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: Now i'm getting this, Result: '..' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: still the same error.

Comment: Windows, and i'm running this from PyCharm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238557/discussion-between-user17242583-and-hightest).

Comment: This what worked for me: capnum = subprocess.getoutput("python3 .\\test-ver2.py")